# Rails: Make the ajax call to the link and scroll to top at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have the following code that generates Ajax call:

```
<% @vegetables.order(:name).each do |vegetable| %>
<%= link_to vegetable.name, fetch_recipes_path(:veg_id => vegetable.id), :remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

and my js file is:

```
 $("#recipes_grid").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'recipes_list', locals: { recipes: @selected } ) %>");
```

which works fine. But I also want to jump to the top of the screen on call. How can I best do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` at the end of your js template to scroll to the top/left of the window.